# How to update components from dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem with updating components outside the dialog. I am opening new dialog through controller:

```
Map<String,Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    options.put("modal", true);
    options.put("draggable", false);
    options.put("resizable", false);
    options.put("contentHeight", 230);
    options.put("contentWidth", 280);

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("wycofanie", options, null);
```

and the dialogbox looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>Wycofanie</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="wycofanie" >
        <ui:include src="potwierdzenie.xhtml"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Wycofaj" action="#{controller.f()}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

After action="#{obslugaRankinguController.wycofajRanking()} I want to update other components on the website. I've tried to do this from controller:

```
context.update("form");
```

and from button adding the update attribute:

```
update="@(form)"
```

but none of this works. How can I do this?

Comment: try using update="@([id$=idofcomponent])"

Comment: @BhavinPanchani it is not working.

Comment: Try using "@form" or "#{p:component('componentIdToUpdate')}". In worst case try "@all" to update full page.

Comment: @Matthias none of this worked for me.